# не получается вывести в консоль src

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <img src="img/1.png">
    <img src="img/2.png">
    <img src="img/3.png">
<script>
let img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(img[0].src);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Хочу понять почему, при выводе в консоль img[0].src выводит не img/1.png а file:///C:/Users/kra92/Desktop/projects/sort-table/img/1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что браузер не может ниоткуда взять какой-нибудь `img/1.png` и показать картинку. Когда путь не указан, берется путь, ведущий к текущему файлу, который записывается в свойстве `.src`. Если нужно получить ровно то, что написано в HTML-атрибуте, надо использовать `.getAttribute()`

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll("img");

console.log( img[0].src);
console.log( img[0].getAttribute('src') );
```

```html
<img src="img/1.png">
<img src="img/2.png">
<img src="img/3.png">
```

P.s. вместо `getElementsByЧтоТо` стоит использовать `querySelectorAll`. Потому что первый возвращает "живой" список элементов и каждый раз при обращении - обновляет его. А второй - один раз собирает элементы и всё.